# SVN post-commit hook not running

Tags: svn, hook, pre-commit-hook, svn-hooks

My svn hook post-commit is not running. I wrote a very simple code in post-commit.sh

```
#! /bin/sh
# POST-COMMIT HOOK
echo apple

echo "apple" >>/tmp/abca.txt
```

but file abca.txt is never created in /tmp folder nor it dumps echo apple.
Please help.

Comment: Where did you put this script? What type of system is your repository hosted on? How are you accessing your repository when you commit (via file:// or http/svn)? Is there sufficient write access to the /tmp folder?

Answer (score 0):

See [this Apache Subversion FAQ entry](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#hook-debugging) for troubleshooting tips. Most likely it's issue with access permissions.